# ConcurrentHashMap Iteration

Tags: java, iterator, concurrenthashmap

ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe , so we can update value of map at the time of iteration . but output of below program is not as i expected.

```
Map concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<();
concurrentHashMap.put("0", "b");
Iterator iterator = concurrentHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
concurrentHashMap.put("8", "k");
concurrentHashMap.put("2", "c");
concurrentHashMap.put("3", "d");
concurrentHashMap.put("1", "e");        
    
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(""+iterator.next());
}
```

output of above code is

> 0=b
>
> 8=k
>
> 3=d
>
> 2=c

expected output

> 1=e
>
> 0=b
>
> 8=k
>
> 3=d
>
> 2=c

Comment: Nobody there who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`ConcurrentHashMap.entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#entrySet()):

> The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.